# C#: using Take() inside foreach is statement is alright to use?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

Can anyone suggest which below two lines of code we should use  ?

```
foreach(var items in itemList.Take(20))
{

}
```

or

```
var itemList = itemList.Take(20);

foreach(var items in itemList)
{

}
```

Does the above two lines have any difference in terms of optimised code and if yes, please do let me know the reason.

Comment: Nitpicking: Note that you cannot redeclare `itemList` in the second example there, and if `itemList` is not `IEnumerable<T>`, but, say, `List<T>`, then simply removing `var` won't work either. This, however, is just an observation and has no impact on my answer.

Comment: They are the same, use whichever is more readable, imho it's version 2.

Comment: both are equally unoptimized

Answer (score 6):

No, the two pieces of code won't behave different.

In fact, if you take a look at this [SharpLab example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgDAAhgRgNwFgBQ8nIHQAyYAdgI4baIoAsFMAzEgEwIDCCA3lgj0ozNQQBZABQBKTt14BfKTzl8kggCoBTAM7BkAHmUA+ESnq69CAMYB7CBFVngYC8TEKumXu4QAzCwCdVAQzMACwQRADd/HwQwYFUAW2jicysbOwdiPGV/AGtVESY4MWc3Dx4ASFZHdStVPAB1HxjVImI8prixCndZEp4GJQQ1TSYTQ2RjfWTrW3tHYvdXUp4IqNi4gAcEAF4p1NmMrNz8wq6l7z9AkPDI6LXEhDX1+aWKqpr6xtiWtrXOhR7pEA=) you'll notice that the two pieces of code compile to the exact same IL.

So:

- The code **looks** different, which if important to *you*, pick the one you feel the most comfortable with
- The code will **compile** to the **exact** same output (in release builds), in which case the looks of the code has (in this case) no bearing on the behavior or performace of the code

In short, pick the version you think looks best.

Comment: Personal opinion: For `Take(20)` I would probably use the former example but if you replace `Take` with a `Where` or similar then I would probably use the latter example, so as to be able to place a breakpoint on the for loop and inspect the filtered collection before looping on it.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` evaluates the method after `in` keyword only once. A very simple example as `ConsoleApplication`:

```
public class Test
{
    public IEnumerable<int> ReturnAList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ReturnAList called");
        return new List<int>()
        {
            1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34
        };
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var test = new Test();
foreach(var t in test.ReturnAList())
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

You will see that the output will be:

```
//  ReturnAList called
//  1
//  1
//  2
//  3
//  5
//  8
//  13
//  21
//  34
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your insight.

However I have written a console application and First example (direct iterating over Take()) consumes more time in execution than the later.